# How long can vestibular neuritis last?

Tags: nervous-system, inner-ear

Is it normal for vestibular neuritis to last longer than two months after taking a course of steroids?

Comment: Hey Urami, welcome to Health! We can’t provide you with differential diagnosis of medical conditions, and as a result are cutting medical background from stories. I’ve edited your question so it can help **anyone** regardless of their medical background. If you disagree with my edit, you can always [edit] the question yourself or revert my edit. While I’m here, I’d like to invite you to take the [tour]. If you still have questions about this site’s policy and else, [meta] is the place to go.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I appreciate it, I wasn't sure if the question was understandable without the background, you made it so much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are four different types of labyrinthitis (or  vestibular neuritis):

- **mastoiditis**
  usually caused by untreatedOtitis Media, middle ear infection
- **lueslabyrinthitis**
  usually caused by a luetic pleurisy or meningitis.
- **mengingogene labyrinthitis**.
  usually caused by meningococcal diseases
- **viral labyrinthitis**.
  usually caused by viral infections

The latter is the most [common type of labyrinthitis](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/001054.htm). Assuming steroids means antibiotics, mengingogene labyrinthitis seems to be your case. If steroids means something like Aciclovir or other virostatic agents, you are suffering from a viral labyrinthitis.

### No matter the cause, 2 months of pain and vertigo is too much

2 months of taking drugs is a lot as well (depending on the drugs you are taking) and should be discussed with your doctor. Don’t hesitate, **take your last results with you**, and visit a doctor of your choice.

---

Further reading (German only): [DocCheck Flexikon](http://m.flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Labyrinthitis)